# Uninstalled programs history on Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, windows, uninstall, history

Is there a way to see a list of programs that have been uninstalled in a Windows 7 machine?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Launch the Event Viewer and open up the section Windows Logs, sub-section Application.

Sort the list by the Source column, then scroll and view the informative events produced by "MsiInstaller".

Comment: That did the trick, thanks! Just a note: the source is "MsiInstaller". And it is better to add a filter by source name on the right panel than to sort and scroll.

Comment: Thank you very very much. You can create a filter on Right panel -> Filter current log -> Filter -> Event sources -> Choose one or more -> like MsiInstaller. Then you can sort by date and time to see the precise moment. Note that some application may not use the standard MSI Installer so won't show there.