# Win8 Event Viewer

Tags: windows-8, installation, history, event-viewer

I recently followed the answer on this site ["Uninstalled Programs History..."](https://superuser.com/questions/233621/uninstalled-programs-history-on-windows-7).

That opened several hours of experimentation with Event Viewer.

My question;
Why are there many installed programs (Many are games) that do not appear in Event Viewer?

Answer (score 2):

It's because the answer you saw is regarding showing you events logged by the MSIInstaller service.

This is the 'usual' [Windows installer system](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Installer), but it's not the only way to install programs.

Some/many programs use their own installer, or none at all.

Those ones may or may not write events, depending on if the author programmed it to or not.

Comment: I understood that, and tried "All Sources" without any new installs. Is there any way to get a list more complete?

Comment: If you'd like a (better) way of getting a list of uninstalled programs like the question to pointed out asks, please earn some rep, head back to the original question, and [place a bounty on it](http://superuser.com/help/bounty), along with comments requesting more/newer answers.